# Moving non-overlapping window in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

What's the best way to move a window over a numpy array so that each individual block does not overlap with the previous one and there is a 1 element gap between the blocks? I guess I should use np.hstack, but I can't figure out the slicing pattern.

Basically what I am looking for is this:

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
result = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
                   [5, 6, 7, 8])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to to achieve in your short example can be done by reshaping the array, then removing the last column to create a "gap".

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

# get length of flat array
a_length, =  a.shape

# reshape array 
#(column by row must respect number of elements)
b = a.reshape(( 2, a_length/2 ))

# assign array except last column to a variable
result = b[:,:-1]
print result
```

Would that be general enough as to answer your question?

Comment: Yes, it would, thanks for the idea. Interestingly enough, i've checked it against the `view_as_blocks` function in `skimage.util` module that uses strides, it's 1.16ms against 58ms for a 2000 elements array on my computer.

Comment: what do you mean by "1.16ms against 58ms for a 2000 elements array"? Keep in mind that your readers do not have beforehand knowledge of what your data consist of, and what you use it for.