# I need to create a list containing all the sums of a list taken three at a time, ie, add first 3 elements then the next 3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I need to add the first three elements of a list then add the next three elements of a list and so forth. This is the code I have got so far:

```
def get_triple_sums_list(a_list):
    new_list = []
    for numbers in range(0,len(a_list)):
        numbers = sum(a_list[:3])
        new_list.append(numbers)
        return new_list
    if a_list == []:
        return []
```

For the list:

```
 [1, 5, 3, 4, 5, 2]
```

This in turn gives me the result:

```
[9]
```

I need to get

```
[9, 11]
```

If the remaining numbers is less than 3, it gives me the remainder of the sum ie,

```
[1, 6, 2, 4, 3]
```

Gives me

```
[9, 7]
```

And

```
[1, 6, 2, 4]
```

Give me

```
[9, 4]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's analyze your code!

```
def get_triple_sums_list(a_list):
    new_list = []
    for numbers in range(0,len(a_list)):
        numbers = sum(a_list[:3]) #You should be using the variable
                                  #numbers here somehow.
       #^^^^^^^ - You are overwriting the for-loop index.
        new_list.append(numbers)
        return new_list  #Why are you returning here? You should be
                         #appending to `new_list`.
    if a_list == []:
        return []
```

---

Here is the fixed code:

```
def get_triple_sums_list(a_list):
    new_list = []
    for index in range(0,len(a_list), 3): #Range takes a 3rd param!
        total = sum(a_list[index:index+3])#Get all the elements from the
                                          #index to index+3
        new_list.append(total)
    return new_list
```

---

UPDATE: It seems there's a shortening contest going on -- and I do not want to be left behind. Here's an ugly version I'd like to add to the list.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> a += [0]*(len(a)%3) #For people who are too lazy to import izip_longest
>>> map(sum,zip(a[::3], a[1::3], a[2::3]))
[6, 15, 15]
```

Answer (score 2):

I like SuperSaiyan's approach of explaining things, I'll be the one who shortens it a bit. You can get the same result with a single comprehension:

```
l = [1, 5, 3, 4, 5, 2]
n = 3    
r = [sum(l[i:i+n]) for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

print(r)
[9, 11]
```

`l[i:i+n]` splits the list in even chunks of length `3` and `sum` takes care of adding these together. Using the `for i in range(0, len(l), n)` we dictate that this operation is to happen for `ceil(len(l) / 3)` times.

Answer (score 1):

Just cuz I like to be different.

```
l = [1, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 42]
g = lambda l,s: [sum(l[i:i+s]) for i in range(0,len(l),s)]
print g(l,3)

#>> [9,12,42]
```

Comment: This is almost the same answers as others, but with a lambda wrapped on the outside.

Comment: Really? That's funny, it's the same question...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26939931/moving-non-overlapping-window-in-numpy
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879735/how-to-implement-a-function-with-non-overlapping-and-rolling-features-simultaneo
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097039/average-on-overlapping-windows-in-python

Answer (score 0):

The other answer mentions the [fault with your code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39828367/4099593). However do note that it's always easier to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in these cases.

```
>>> l =  [1, 5, 3, 4, 5, 2]
>>> [sum(l[i:i+3]) for i in range(0,len(l),3)]
[9, 11]
```

It also works for un-mod-3 lists

```
>>> l =  [1, 5, 3, 4, 5]
>>> [sum(l[i:i+3]) for i in range(0,len(l),3)]
[9, 9]
```

See [What does "list comprehension" mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-in-python-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-us)  for more details about a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may achieve it by using `map()` with `lambda` function as:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 5, 3, 4, 5, 2]
>>> list(map(lambda x: sum(my_list[x:x+3]), range(0, len(my_list), 3)))
[9, 11]
```

Comment: You could just say: `[sum(my_list[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(my_list), 3)]`

Comment: It was already answered here. However removed that solution, as it was not the right way to do it even though it was working

Comment: In my opinion, it is a more pythonic way of achieving the same thing. I am not sure why you'd consider it wrong. (List comprehension is more *pythonic* than map/lambda combination)

Comment: Yes. I agree on that. I meant that the solution with *list comprehension* is already mentioned here. That's why I haven't mentioned that. Instead the one I removed was having list comprehension + map, which was not at all pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different way of doing it using `zip_longest` from `itertools` (`izip_longest` in python2), it splits the list in three lists then zip them to get packs of three elements and finally sums the packs:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
a=[1, 6, 2, 4, 3]
b=zip_longest(a[0::3],a[1::3],a[2::3],fillvalue=0)
result=[sum(x) for x in b]
>>>[9, 7]
```